# Optimizing PDF using CDF deltas

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, cumulative-distribution-function, quantiles

In the paper introducing [PixelCNN++](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.05517) they optimize the PDF of a logistic function by minimizing the difference between the CDF around the sample points (x ± epsilon). I am trying to understand when it would be better to optimize the PDF in this way instead of straight-forward MLE approaches and the only thing I found is [this comment on github](https://github.com/openai/pixel-cnn/issues/38#issuecomment-462137500) which seems to suggest that there is more information in the CDF than in the PDF.

My question is when would it be better to optimize using the CDF delta versus an MLE method and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant formulas from the paper:
[image: See formulas (1) and (2) from the paper]

In (2) a logistic CDF is used because $x$ is a discretized version of $\nu$. Indeed, $x$ takes on integer values from $\{0, \dots, 255\}$, whereas $\nu$ could take any value on $\mathbb{R}$.

Thus, to work with discretized values, one needs to compute their PMF, which is achieved by integrating $\nu$'s PDF over discretization bins. Assuming $x = \text{round}(\nu)$ discretization,

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{Pr}[\text{round}(\nu) = y]
&= \text{Pr}[y - 0.5 \le \nu \le y + 0.5] \\
&= \text{Pr}[\nu \le y + 0.5] - \text{Pr}[\nu \le y - 0.5] \\
&= F_\nu(y + 0.5) - F_\nu(y - 0.5)
\end{align*}
$$
Where $F_\nu$ is $\nu$'s CDF.